# reading file by fscanf and saving into int array

Tags: c, arrays, file, int, scanf

I have a a.txt include the following:

```
A 50 60 70
B 80 90 100
```

I'm trying to save it into a student struct using the code below but it doesn't save me the last two grades of each student.
I've opened the file in the main.
pls. advice what's wrong?

```
 typedef struct student{
    char name[20];
    int grades[3];
    }student;


while(fscanf(fp,"%s%d%d%d",stu[i-1].name,&stu[i-1].grades[0],&stu[i-1].grades[1],&stu[i-1].grades[2])!=EOF)
```

Comment: 1) Post `stu` declaration. 2) do not test against `!= EOF` but against `== 4`.  3) Real problem is elsewhere in code - suspect it is in indexing `stu[]`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! the problem was the spaces between %s %d %d %d.

Comment: the problem is _not_ "the spaces between %s %d %d %d".  You have solved the problem by changing other aspects of your code or input.